# How to extract object from set by part of fields in its class

Tags: java, set, equals

Assume I have some class

```
public class CashCard {
    private String lastName;
    private int pinCode;
    private int balance;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getPinCode() {
        return pinCode;
    }

    public void setPinCode(int pinCode) {
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public int takeMoney(int money) throws NotEnoughMoneyException {
        if (money > balance)
            throw new NotEnoughMoneyException();

        balance -= money;
        return money;
    }

    public int putMoney(int money) {
        balance += money;
        return money;
    }

    public CashCard(String lastName, int pinCode, int balance) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || o.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        CashCard that = (CashCard) o;
        return this.lastName.equals(that.lastName) && this.pinCode == that.pinCode;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        int prime = 31;

        result = result * prime + lastName.hashCode();
        result = result * prime + pinCode;

        return result;
    }
}
```

the main point in this class is that it has 3 fields but for 2 objects of this class if they have same(equivalent) two fields they are equal no matter what third field is for each of them

Next, for example I have some set of this objects

```
CashCard card1 = new CashCard("Goldman", 1111, 9000);
CashCard card2 = new CashCard("Miranda", 1234, 100);
CashCard card3 = new CashCard("Grey", 6969, 1000000);

Set<CashCard> cashCards = new HashSet<CashCard>();
cashCards.add(card1);
cashCards.add(card2);
cashCards.add(card3);
```

The last thing - I have last name and pincode

```
String lastName = "Goldman";
int pincode = 1111;
```

I need to figure out if set contains element with such name and pincode AND if it is so, change that element in set in some way.

Comment: Look into implementing equals() and hashCode(), creating a subset CashCardKey class, and using a map instead.

Comment: You'd have to iterate through the set, checking values, either using the equals() function as suggested above, or individually checking the Strings. Have you considered using a Map instead or is the Set a requirement? You've described something that has a key (in this case a pair of values) that makes them equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract the object which matches some constraint directly. You can only check for containment. To actually *find* that particular object you're after, you'll have to iterate over the set using an iterator and compare each object with the one you've constructed. That is, do something as follows:

```
for (CashCard cc : cashCards)
    if (cc.equals(new CashCard("Goldman", 1111, 0L))
        cc.balance -= toDebit;
```

If you don't share the reference in other places, you could also remove the CashCard and insert a new CashCard with the updated property:

```
CashCard newCard = new CashCard("Goldman", 1111, newBalance);
cashCards.remove(newCard);
cashCards.add(newCard);
```

I would strongly advice you to rethink your design though. Excluding one field from equals/hashcode is a real code smell. Consider making `CashCard` contain name+pin and use a `Map<CashCard, Long> balanceMap` for balances instead.

Comment: What about same name and same zip code ? Need to add an auto increment id to the class.

Comment: hate autocorrect yes you are correct i meant pin code.

Comment: @Aeshang, still not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: That wasn't much of a clarification. I don't understand why OP would need to add some auto increment id.

Comment: say if you have 2 object new CashCard("aioobe","1234",100); &  new CashCard("aioobe","1234",10000); the code doesn't prevent this... What will happen when you do your code to this ? depending on the instance that is returned it will deduct money.

Comment: As the code stands, both objects would equal each other (since equals/hashCode doesn't take balance into account). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Consider a scenario where it like this CashCard card1 = new CashCard("YourName", 1111, 9999);CashCard card2 = new CashCard("YourName", 1111, 1111);Set<CashCard> cashCards = new HashSet<CashCard>();cashCards.add(card1);cashCards.add(card2); the set here will have 2 values. now if you  wanted to do withdraw 2000 depending on you return value it would allow you or not allow you to do it as you might not have sufficient funds. do you understand now ?

Comment: *the set here will have 2 values* -- No, the set can not contain two values that are equal. The second call to `add` will have no effect. Do you understand?

Comment: All I'm saying is that it will over write the first one or will keep the first and discard the second one this would depend on the HashSet implementation which can change from one java version to another ... object so he/she needs an id ... to avoid a weird behavior Do you understand it ?

Comment: A) You're wrong, read [the documentation for add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-) B) It's not relevant here considering the title: *How to extract object from set by part of fields in its class*.